# C++: File open call fails

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following code in one of my library functions that I am calling many times in a loop. After a large number of iterations I find that `open` returns -1 which it shouldn't have as the previous iterations worked fine. What may be the cause. How can I get more details on the error.?

```
int mode;
 if (fileLen == 0)
      mode = O_TRUNC | O_RDWR | O_CREAT;
 else
      mode = O_RDWR;
 myFilDes = open (fName, mode, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

EDIT:After the end of each iteration I am calling a method that library exposes which internally calls `close (myFilDes);`

Comment: If you open a new file each time without closing the other ones, you may just be out of file handles.

Comment: Do you close the file after `open`?

Comment: Yes I am closing after every iteration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

perror is the standard function to map errno to string and print it out to stderr:

```
if (myFilDes == -1)
    perror("Unable to open file: ");
```

man errno / man perror / man strerror for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Are you closing these handles as well?  Do you reach a specific number of open calls before it starts failing?

The **errno** variable should have additional information as to what the failure is.  See: http://linux.die.net/man/2/open

Comment: After the end of each iteration I am calling a method that library exposes which internally calls `close (myFilDes);`

Comment: How tp get the errno? Is there a function I can call?

Comment: @iJeeves `errno` is a global var. Just use it as any other variable.